# Why pasta keeps always damp and moist when I cook it?

Tags: pasta, boiling

Boiling pasta in itself is easy - however, there's a problem I could never avoid or solve. When I judge the pasta is ready, I pour the unnecessary water out of the vessel, though even if I use a colander, the pasta keeps damp and moist, and even if I put it back to the fridge for a night or two, it keeps like that. Even adding salt and oil to the water did not help it.

What can I do against it?

Comment: What are you expecting the pasta to do instead? Boiling pasta causes it to absorb water.

Comment: Maybe you are cooking your pasta too soft. Try making it Semi-al dente, and don't forget to shake or toss the pasta while it is the the colander so any trapped water can escape. If stores for later, the al dente pasta will soft up a little as the water continues to spread into the center of the pasta.

Comment: Mixing in some olive oil immediately after draining the water may help avoid the pasta clumping, if that's what you're asking about.

Comment: Nem értem a kérdést. Mi baja van a tésztának?

Comment: possibly related (if the comments are correct in what the issue is) : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/11929/67

Comment: @Joe Oh, yes, judging from the answer of Ecnerwal I guess this is the case.

Comment: add oil AFTER you cooked and drain the pasta, NOT before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refrigeration does not improve pasta texture; on that front my advice is to cook only as much as you are going to eat each time.

Other than that, it sounds like you are overcooking the pasta, so "when you judge it done" appears to be in error, and you should alter your judgement to an earlier point if you find the pasta too wet/soft they way you have been doing it. The time needed varies depending on the shape. When it is done it should be removed from the water (or the water removed from it) immediately.

I find no benefit to adding oil to the water - save the oil for adding just after it's been drained if you want it to do something useful.

Answer (score 2):

Consider that it may be a problem with the pasta you are buying. Some pasta types are more prone to become waterlogged than others.

Try using a decent pasta brand. Not necessarily the most expensive one you can find, something widespread like Barilla will do. The point is to be sure it meets some minimum standards for quality, as the discounter's own brands are hit and miss.

Also, I find that egg pasta's texture feels less soggy. It's possible that you have been eating egg pasta in restaurants but making semolina pasta at home. Try an egg pasta to see if it feels better to you.

Of course, this comes in addition to the "correct cooking time" advice. You can cook any pasta to mush if you don't get it out in time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to conserve for some time your pasta, when in colander wash it immediately with plenty cold water to cool immediately. Also if you want to conserve it add some oil and ground cheese after cooking to keep from sticking all together. In "ristorante" normally pasta is semi cooked and when required placed in boiling water for few minutes before serving it. Personally i like conserved pasta when in "minestrone" that is in vegetable soup, but is very good also fried with some ground cheese like parmesan, gruyere or emmenthaler.